# Wordpress redirect on password to certain page

Tags: wordpress

My client would like to give each customer a password and once entered, this should then redirect them to a certain page. I.e. password 'cake' would go to a page about cakes, password 'cats' would go to a page about cats. Sounds simple enough, is there a plugin that you guys are aware of that would do it? Or is it possible straight from WP itself?
Thanks

Comment: where the users will enter the password? Where and who will generate the passwords?

Comment: The site admin would create the password and associate this with a page. The customer would visit a page e.g. 'Client Login' and simply enter a password (nothing else) to redirect them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Peter's Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/).  I haven't used it myself, but it has good ratings, has been updated recently, and it sounds like it can redirect based on the login criteria entered.

On a side note, I can't wait to see this website that features cats and cakes!

Good luck.

Comment: That looks ideal to be honest, thanks!  I'll update as soon as I've got it installed.

Comment: Ok for that plugin the customer has to be a registered 'user' on the site.  What I'm trying to do is redirect simply on a password, no registration required.

Comment: Gotcha.  Let me see if I can find a better solution for you.  If it is based on page, could it just be done with `.htaccess` Rewrite rules?

Comment: Probably but the problem is it needs to be fairly easy to update (I preferably won't be doing the updates) by the client for their customers.

Comment: Just coming back to this...any other ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better solutions out there. I accomplished what you are looking for by using conditional fields and html in Gravity forms. To mimic a password, I removed the Gravity forms submit button, and I basically created my own submit button in the html field to redirect the visitor to my desired url. Using conditional fields, I hide the button until the user enters the exact passphrase.

This method also allowed me to create hide/show multiple buttons matching different passcodes. We give private clients different passcodes to redirect them to different pages and content.

Answer (score -2):

I've searched for hours for that solution! Here You go @ajguk: http://thecodecave.com/plugins/smart-passworded-pages/ or http://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-passworded-pages/
The plugin is called "Smart passwor pages" (for those experts that can't reed what the link says). It is as close as it gets 4 me. The plugin is old, but it works. Instalation is simple. You just need to put shortcode [smartpwpages] on a page which gives You a login field and every childpage under page with shortcode (if passworded protected throug WP) will work exactly like you asked. You will need to enter into login field only a password and it will redirect user to a page that this password protects... Just need to make your passwords unique for every childpage. 
Cheers!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: my answer is usefull. anyone that can read will google for smart passworded pages plugin which is the solution and is in the link. I don't supose that stackoverflow.com will overlive wordpress.org so what's your problem with the links? dead link isn't end of the road if U know what i mean ;)